# Can't deploy Xamarin.iOS app to device using XCode 9.3

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xcode9.3

After upgrading to XCode 9.3 (9E145), I can no longer use Xamarin and deploy to any of my iOS devices.

I run Visual Studio 2017 on a PC and use a Mac as build agent. Until the upgrade everything worked just fine, but now I cannot deploy any apps anymore.

I get an error complaining about a missing framework 'DADocSetAccess':

> Launch failed. The app 'iOSTest1' could not be launched on 'My iPhone'. 
>   Error: error HE0003: Could not load the framework 'DADocSetAccess' (path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DADocSetAccess.framework/DADocSetAccess): not found.. Please check the logs for more details. The app has been terminated.

I can confirm that the missing framework is not present on my Mac.

I have also tried to use Visual Studio on my Mac, but that fails with the same error. However, I created a testapp in XCode and it worked just fine - so I suspect the error is related to Xamarin/XCode somehow.

I have spent many hours trying to reinstalling XCode twice, but the problem is still there. It is also no longer possible to run on a simulator using VS2017, which also worked just fine before the XCode 9.3 update.

I cannot understand what these frameworks are used for, as it works just fine to deploy and run apps from XCode.

Is anyone else also having this problem?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Xamarin will release an update to support xcode 9.3. In the future, avoid updating xcode before checking if there is a Xamarin.iOS update to support it. https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-xcode-9-3/

Comment: Thanks Pedro. So you think I took it a bit too early and that Xamarin will release an update soon? The main reason I upgraded it was that was asked to deploy to an iPhone with iOS 11.3.

Comment: Same mistake today, I just started doing active Xamarin dev any idea how quick MS gets that kind of update out the door?

Comment: @Shawn, I don't know for sure, but think that it would be not so quick as we want to be, because I think that Apple has changed the way how Xcode deploys the application, and that can be a serious change. But however I wish MS to solve this issue as soon as it can be possible

Comment: This is not good enough. Since the preview of 9.3 came out, Visual Studio for Mac has pushed four headlines to the "Welcome Page" none of which says WARNING AVOID XCODE 9.3

Comment: I can also confirm this is working fine now with 9.3 latest vs mac and vs 2017 updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stable channel now supports Xcode 9.3 (I was on the beta channel)

Switch to the stable channel or download the latest updates and it should work now.

These are the versions that have the update:

- Visual Studio for Mac **7.4.2.12**
- Visual Studio Tools for Xamarin
  **4.9.0.753**
- Xamarin.iOS **11.9.1.24**
- Xamarin Remoted iOS Simulator **1.2.4.12**

More Info [here](https://releases.xamarin.com/service-release-15-6-5/)

Answer (score 2):

For now, you can download xcode 9.2 before xamarin can handle xcode 9.3. Can download 9.2 at https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Just as a reference:
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/3837

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin has just fixed this issue. If you use Mac then just update your VS for Mac. The fix for Windows VS will be in version 15.6.5 which is not available yet, but you can download and install necessary package for Xamarin right now. Just go to the link below:
https://releases.xamarin.com/service-release-15-6-5/

**UPD:** The fix for Windows is now available. Just download VS 15.6.5